# How to post form values created by loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to get post values from form created using loop,

Here is my controller

```
    $valuepost=$this->input->post('value');

if($valuepost==1){
    $val1=array('NoOfinput' => $this->input->post('val1input'),'NoOfbox' => $this->input->post('val1box'),'boxvalue' => null);
    $val=array($val1);
    } 
    elseif($valuepost==2){
    $val1=array('NoOfinput' => $this->input->post('val1input'),'NoOfbox' => $this->input->post('val1box'),'boxvalue' => null);
    $val2=array('NoOfinput' => $this->input->post('val2input'),'NoOfbox' => $this->input->post('val2box'),'boxvalue' => null);
    $val=array($val1,$val2);
    }   
        elseif($valuepost==3){
    $val1=array('NoOfinput' => $this->input->post('val1input'),'NoOfbox' => $this->input->post('val1box'),'boxvalue' => null);
    $val2=array('NoOfinput' => $this->input->post('val2input'),'NoOfbox' => $this->input->post('val2box'),'boxvalue' => null);
    $val3=array('NoOfinput' => $this->input->post('val3input'),'NoOfbox' => $this->input->post('val3box'),'boxvalue' => null);

    $val=array($val1,$val2,$val3);
    }

    elseif($valuepost==4){
    $val1=array('NoOfinput' => $this->input->post('val1input'),'NoOfbox' => $this->input->post('val1box'),'boxvalue' => null);
    $val2=array('NoOfinput' => $this->input->post('val2input'),'NoOfbox' => $this->input->post('val2box'),'boxvalue' => null);
    $val3=array('NoOfinput' => $this->input->post('val3input'),'NoOfbox' => $this->input->post('val3box'),'boxvalue' => null);
    $val4=array('NoOfinput' => $this->input->post('val4input'),'NoOfbox' => $this->input->post('val4box'),'boxvalue' => null);

    $val=array($val1,$val2,$val3,$val4);
    }

 echo val;
```

How to simplify this using loop or foreach , Please help with the solution required

Comment: `foreach` ?? `switch` is best on this. Can you elaborate more about your question? As well post the form code too.

Answer (score 0):

Using (int) to cast your post value into an int.

```
$valuepost = (int) $this->input->post('value');
// declaring the array that will store the final result
$val = [];

// looping as many times as necessary
for ($i = 1; $i <= $valuepost; $i++) {
    $val[] = [
        'NoOfinput' => $this->input->post('val' . $i . 'input'),
        'NoOfbox' => $this->input->post('val' . $i . 'box'),
        'boxvalue' => null,
    ];
}

var_dump($val);
```

You also should check before looping if $valuepost is not to high (if you are sure that it won't be over 4 by example) :

```
if ($valuepost > 4) {
    throw new \Exception('Must not be over 4.');
}
```

(an exception or a redirection)